# How to change EditText cursor z position?

Tags: android, android-edittext, cursor, placeholder

I have an EditText and set placeholder.
I think this look is weird because of the cursor is under the text. (see below picture) How can I control this cursor z-position or gravity?

[image]

Code:

```
// in Layout
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/content_edit"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
    android:background="@null"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:hint="@{contentHintText}"
    android:lineSpacingExtra="6dp"
    android:minHeight="80dp"
    android:text="@{contentText}"
    android:textColor="@color/gray_66"
    android:textColorHint="@color/gray_cc"
    android:textSize="13dp" />

// in Activity
binding.editContainer.setContentHintText(Html.fromHtml(myHint));
```

Comment: Even if you'll find a way to do it, is it really what you want? It's like that by default in Android. In my opinion it makes sense not to hide the text...

Comment: @Had Shafran Yes. This EditText's behavior is default things. But also I think there are some people who it could felt awkward. I want to know the probability of control of cursor layer.

Comment: Can you place your edittext code over here.

Comment: @Siddharth Patel I added my code.

Comment: I just add space to the head of text. Like this. `" " + Html.fromHtml(myHint)`

Comment: Remove hint and set only text then try if it is focusing or not

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.inbox);
et.setSelection(et.getText().length());
```

set gravity in edittext xml

```
android:gravity="top"
```

or in java code:-

```
editText.setGravity(Gravity.TOP);
```

Comment: Thank for your answer. and sorry for my question was not enough to explain in detail. in detail, My question is how can I bring the cursor to over the text layer?

Comment: Do you want your cursor to be blink above text?

Comment: Yes. That is my question. @Siddharth Patel

Answer (score 0):

You may use `&#160;` at the front of you hint string.